# How to pass in variables inside function calls at onclick?

Tags: javascript, variables, dom, scope, onclick

I have a doubt as to how to pass variables into a function call that is inside an `onclick` attribute. *It's actually a bad practice but I still want to know in case I ever need.*

For Example:

```js
let parsed = document.querySelector('input').value.replace('/\^/','**');
function evaluat(expr){
    console.log(eval(expr));
  }
```

```html
<input></input>
<p><button onclick="evaluat(parsed)">Compute</button></p>
```

This code prints `undefined` for the input `5^2` instead of the expected `25`.

Comment: You don't.  `onclick` triggeres a function. In this function, retrieve the values you want using `document.getElementById(yourId).value` or `document.querySelector(selector).value`

Comment: So I can't use a custom variable inside `onclick` attribute?

Comment: I know it's bad practice, but I want to know it in case if I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you start your page with the input empty, the `parsed` variable has already been evaluated to `''`. In your `evaluat` (should be `evaluate`) function, you haven't retrieved the value of `document.querySelector('input').value` again, so the function has `eval`ed an empty string, which is why it logs `undefined`.

You'll need to make changes to the function to be something like...

```js
function evaluat() {
  console.log(
    eval(document.querySelector('input').value.replace(/\^/,'**'))
  );
}
```

You won't have to pass any arguments into this function, since it will query the DOM each time it is executed.

By the way, note that `eval()` is dangerous. Avoid using it.

Comment: I used `evaluat` because `evaluate` is already present.

Comment: Glad my explanation helps!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use [a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), and pass in the input to the function that's returned as the click listener.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', evaluat(input), false);

function evaluat(input) {
  return function () {
    const str = input.value.replace('^', '**');
    console.log(eval(str));
  }
}
```

```html
<input></input>
<p><button>Replace</button></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you give your element a unique id to avoid ambiguity.

```js
function evaluat(expr) {
  let val = document.getElementById('parsed').value.replace('^', '**');
  console.log(eval(val));
}
```

```html
<input id="parsed"></input>
<p><button  onclick="evaluat()">Replace</button></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Because `onclick` is a javascript function, you can use javascript inside of it like that :

```js
function evaluat(expr){
  console.log(eval(expr));
}
```

```html
<input></input>
<p><button onclick="evaluat(document.querySelector('input').value.replace('/\^/','**'))">Replace</button></p>
```

But you can't use javascript stored variable inside html. But you can use function that returns the value you want :

```js
function evaluat(expr){
  console.log(eval(expr));
}

var parse = function () {
  return document.querySelector('input').value.replace('/\^/','**');
};

var parse2 = document.querySelector('input').value.replace('/\^/','**')
```

```html
<input></input>
<p><button onclick="evaluat(parse())">Replace</button></p> <!-- OK -->
<p><button onclick="evaluat(parse2)">Replace</button></p> <!-- undefined -->
```